# How to efficiently create an indexed list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings, and another list of unique strings:

```
import numpy as np
source_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat']
unique_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat']  # unique_list = np.unique(source_list)
```

How do I create the `indexed_list` (which contains the indices of the `unique_list` in the `source_list`)

```
indexed_list = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2]
```

I know the following implementation would work fine. But, is there an more **efficient** and **pythonic** way to create `indexed_list`?

```
indexed_list = [None]*len(source_list)
for index, item in enumerate(source_list):
  indexed_list[index] = np.where(unique_list == item)[0][0]

print(indexed_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.unique` with additional parameters:

```
unique, index = np.unique(['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat'], return_inverse=True)
```

Comment: A simple solution to simultaneously find `unique_list` and the `indexed_list`

Answer (score 2):

This is where Python shines - **list comprehensions**.

```py
source_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat']
unique_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat']
indexed_list = [unique_list.index(item) for item in source_list]
print(indexed_list) # [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2]
```

Simple, elegant, beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map` to solve this problem:

```
source_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'rat']
unique_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat']
indexed_list = map(unique_list.index, source_list)

print(*indexed_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
0 1 1 0 0 2
>
```

Although `map` returns a "map object", not a list, that isn't necessarily a problem -- it depends on what's the *next step* for the result.  The next step might simply accept this iterator or you may have to convert via `list`.

Delaying resolution to a finished structure until needed is as pythonic as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
indices = {a: i for i, a in enumerate(unique_list)}
indexed_list = [indices[a] for a in source_list]
print(indexed_list)
```